# error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1 - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Buenas tardes,
mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy recibiendo un error en cada una de las llamadas que hago al servicio REST. Este error desaparece cambiar cualquier cosa en el código (incluyendo tan sólo "//" por ejemplo), pero la primera vez que compila siempre falla.

Me gustaría saber si alguien entiende el problema.

Como ya he dicho antes, el código funciona. Pero falla la primera vez.
Adjunto un ejemplo:

```
/** GET carsfrom the server */
    getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
        return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.carsUrl)
            .map(response => {
                let res = response.json().cars;
                if (!Array.isArray(res)) {
                    return [res]
                }
                return res;
            })
            .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getCars Error', []))
            );
    }
```

El error se produce en la primera línea del return. El error producido es el siguiente:

error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

Comment: dentro de `if (!Array.isArray(res)) {` -> `return [res]` no tiene `;`

Comment: Gracias. Ha sido un Typo. Pero ese no es lo que causa el error.

Comment: Resuelto. Era necesario cambiar lo siguiente> "return this.http.get(this.systemsUrl)"

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que especificaba un tipo al realizar la operacion. En este caso, el tipo era System

**Codigo final**

```
/** GET carsfrom the server */
    getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.carsUrl)
            .map(response => {
                let res = response.json().cars;
                if (!Array.isArray(res)) {
                    return [res]
                }
                return res;
            })
            .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getCars Error', []))
            );
    }
```

**Eliminado**

```
this.http.get/*<Car[]>*/
```